# DESeq Error: Some values in assay are negative

Tags: r

I am running a DESeq analysis through importing counts from FeatureCounts. I generate the counts matrix but when I get to running the DESeqMatrixFromDataSet, I get the following error. I have checked my counts several times and I don't see any negative results.

I will appreciate any help with this.

```
    library(purrr)
    library(tidyverse)
    f_files<- list.files("C:/Users/cash/Desktop/DESeq analysis 2", pattern = "\\.txt$", full.names = T)
    
    read_in_feature_counts<- function(file){
      cnt<- read_tsv(file, col_names =T, comment = "#")
      cnt<- cnt %>% dplyr::select(-Chr, -Start, -End, -Strand, -Length)
      return(cnt)
    }
    
    raw_counts<- map(f_files, read_in_feature_counts)
    raw_counts_df<- purrr::reduce(raw_counts, inner_join) 
    head(raw_counts_df)
    
    # Assign condition (first four are controls, second four contain the expansion)
    condition <- factor(c("Donor1-1_S1_R2_001", "Donor1-2_S2_R2_001", "Donor2-1_S10_R2_001", "Donor2-2_S11_R2_001","Donor3-1_S1_R2_001", "Donor3-2_S2_R2_001", "Donor4-1_S10_R2_001", "Donor4-2_S11_R2_001"))
    
    library(DESeq2)
    
    # Create a coldata frame and instantiate the DESeqDataSet. See ?DESeqDataSetFromMatrix
    coldata <- data.frame(row.names=colnames(raw_counts_df))
    
    
    dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=raw_counts_df, colData=coldata, design=~condition)
    
    **Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : 
      some values in assay are negative**
```

Here is the new error:

```
> dds <- DESeqDataSetFromMatrix(countData=raw_counts_df, colData=coldata, design=~condition)
converting counts to integer mode
Error in DESeqDataSet(se, design = design, ignoreRank) : 
  all variables in design formula must be columns in colData
```

Comment: How are you checking for negative values? I might use `any(raw_counts_df < 0)`

Comment: Thanks for responding. It says FALSE

Comment: > any(raw_counts_df < 0)
[1] FALSE
>

Comment: what about `class(raw_counts_df)` and `typeof(raw_counts_df)`?

Comment: > class(raw_counts_df)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Comment: > typeof(raw_counts_df)
[1] "list"

Comment: This doesn't make sense in terms of your code above, where you have two definitions of `raw_counts_data`, and the second one would make it a 'matrix'. But what does `sapply(raw_counts_df, class)` say, in particular are they all `numeric` or `integer`?

Comment: Sorry, please ignore the second code for raw_counts_df where I am trying to read it as a matrix, I was just trying to fix my previous code. This data is for

Comment: The first part of the code. raw_counts<- map(f_files, read_in_feature_counts)
raw_counts_df<- purrr::reduce(raw_counts, inner_join)

Comment: > sapply(raw_counts_df, class) 
                 Geneid  Donor1-1_S1_R2_001.bam  Donor1-2_S2_R2_001.bam 
            "character"               "numeric"               "numeric" 
Donor2-1_S10_R2_001.bam Donor2-2_S11_R2_001.bam  Donor3-1_S1_R2_001.bam 
              "numeric"               "numeric"               "numeric" 
 Donor3-2_S2_R2_001.bam Donor4-1_S10_R2_001.bam Donor4-2_S11_R2_001.bam 
              "numeric"               "numeric"               "numeric"

Comment: It says numeric for the bam files, but character for the Gene ID. Could this be the issue? How can I fix it

Comment: From your description it looks you should NOT use the Geneid column when you are creating the `coldata` data.frame and when calling `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix()`. You should edit your question to remove the second assignment of `raw_counts_df`, and include the output of something like `head(raw_counts_df)` immediately before calling `DESeqDataSetFromMatrix()` so that it is easier to understand what you are doing.

Comment: > head(raw_counts_df)
# A tibble: 6 x 9
  Geneid         `Donor1-1_S1_R~` `Donor1-2_S2_R~` `Donor2-1_S10_~` `Donor2-2_S11_~`
  <chr>                     <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>            <dbl>
1 ENST000006192~                9               11                7                5
2 ENST000004733~                0                0                0                0

Comment: How can I edit out the gene ID column ?

Comment: If it is the first column, then `raw_counts_df[,-1]`. I *think* you can edit your question, rather than just posting comments, by clicking the 'Edit' button below your question.

Comment: I have a new error on design , but it seems the negative error was solved

Comment: I edited your question to include a little text and a 'fence' (three back-ticks, \`\`\`) before and after the code chunk. I think you want to add 'condition' to coldata, e.g., `data.frame(row.names = colnames(raw_counts_df, condition = condition)`.

Comment: Now i have a new error

Comment: coldata <- data.frame(row.names=colnames(raw_counts_df_2), condition = condition)
Error in data.frame(row.names = colnames(raw_counts_df_2), condition = condition) : 
  row names supplied are of the wrong length

Comment: I really appreciate your time, I think we are almost there

Comment: It's much better to edit your question with the updated script that you're using; for instance I do not know what `raw_counts_df_2` is. I guess `length(condition)` returns 8 (because there are 8 elements in your script above) but `length(colnames(raw_counts_df_2))` returns some other number (because the number and / or order of columns in `raw_counts_df_2` is different from the values in `condition`).

Comment: IT worked!!! I have been stuck for 5 days!!! Thank you Martin!

Comment: You might find the Bioconductor support forum https://support.bioconductor.org a good source of information / support about DESeq2 and other R / Bioinformatics tasks.